# .NET Core .csproj Output Path not working correctly

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm using Visual Studio 14 (VS 2015) Update 3 and I want to build a REST API based .Net Core 1, using Kestrel as the server.

I want to be able to use a **.csproj** instead of the old **.xproj** in order to use MSBuild as I do in other projects. To do so, I've used the [tutorial they have](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/target-dotnetcore-with-msbuild.md).

The problem is that when I define "OutputPath" as "bin\Debug" (for Debug mode, for instance), Visual Studio builds the project and sets build's results to "bin\Debug\\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\win7-x64".

If I use the *.xproj* and build, the results are stored at "bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0", which is the expected behaviour.

What is happening?

.csproj:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
    <BaseNuGetRuntimeIdentifier>win7</BaseNuGetRuntimeIdentifier>
    <TargetFrameworkIdentifier>.NETCoreApp</TargetFrameworkIdentifier>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v1.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <NoStdLib>true</NoStdLib>
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1701</NoWarn>
    <ProjectGuid>{D21ABA46-65F9-4B47-882C-F9C0765052DD}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>MyAPP</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>MyAPP</AssemblyName>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>.\obj\Debug</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <OutputPath>.\bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>.\bin\Release</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="src\**\*.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="project.json" />
    <None Include="appsettings.json" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\DotNet.Web\Microsoft.DotNet.Web.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- We don't use any of MSBuild's resolution logic for resolving the framework, so just set these two
            properties to any folder that exists to skip the GetReferenceAssemblyPaths task (not target) and
            to prevent it from outputting a warning (MSB3644).
        -->
    <_TargetFrameworkDirectories>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)</_TargetFrameworkDirectories>
    <_FullFrameworkReferenceAssemblyPaths>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)</_FullFrameworkReferenceAssemblyPaths>
    <!-- MSBuild thinks all EXEs need binding redirects, not so for CoreCLR! -->
    <AutoUnifyAssemblyReferences>true</AutoUnifyAssemblyReferences>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>false</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <!-- Set up debug options to run with host, and to use the CoreCLR debug engine -->
    <StartAction>Program</StartAction>
    <StartProgram>$(TargetDir)</StartProgram>
    <DebugEngines>{2E36F1D4-B23C-435D-AB41-18E608940038}</DebugEngines>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0"
  },

  "runtimes": {
    "win7-x64": {},
    "ubuntu.14.04-x64": {},
    "osx.10.10-x64": {}
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [ "dnxcore50", "portable-net452" ]
    }
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish --publish-folder ./bin" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of porting the file over manually have you tried runing `dotnet migrate` which should migrate your project.json file over to the new system

Comment: This was before Microsoft going back to .csproj. Thanks anyway for your answer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `<AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>`